# what's the difference in between ? or / in an http request

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm starting on nestjs and here I am with a very simple question ... I need to set up a controller on my application that has a delete handler with the path (`'/: id'`). To get into this handler via postman I just need to reach it through (http://localhost:3000/tasks/id), but the handler is specified that way: (deleteTask (@Param('id') id: string) - In that case, via postman I just needed to include the id in the 'Query Params' ... Consequently, my HTTP request would be this way (http://localhost:3000/tasks?id=xxx). Finally, my question is, 
**what's the difference between the @Param who brings '/' and Query Param that converts in '?'**

Here is my handler:

```js
@Delete('/:id')
    deleteTask(@Param('id') id: string){
        return this.taskService.deleteTask(id);
    }
```

[image: Request with 'Params' in Postman - ?]

[image: Request without 'Params' in Postman - /]

Comment: Maybe start by learning what the structure of an URL is – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The `/` is a path.**

> The path (or stem) in the URL is analogous to the file path for a file on your computer. It often has an inherent drilldown/tree structure that uses “/”s in some organizing fashion. The path can also include the filename, if there is one: index.htm, products.php, about.html, etc.

**The `?` is a query/parameter.**
An optional query component preceded by a question mark (?)

> Parameters are nothing more than a list of variables in the URL. There is no limit (well, there are overall URL length limits, but lets not go there) to the number of parameters that can be included in a URL. But, there are a few hard-and-fast rules about parameters:
>
> - They must be separated from the URL’s path using a “?”
> - They must be separated from each other (when there are multiple parameters involved) using a “&” (this “must” is a little squishy — you can put subparameters inside of a single parameter using a little developer legerdemain…but that, too, is beyond the scope of this post)
> - They must be structured as a “key-value pair.” The “key” is the name of the variable, while the “value” is the actual, well, value of the variable. The key goes on the left side of an “=” sign, and the value goes on the right side.

Comment: But why the @Param doesnt receive the parameter with the '?' ?